# Поменять слова местами

Tags: javascript, строки

Здравствуйте. Имеется строка: 'DN63  1/4"GM 0/0,6bar' нужно поменять с помощью JS первое слово и второе, что бы получилось '1/4"GM DN63 0/0,6bar'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Бьём строку по пробелам на массив, и составляем новый из 1-го, 0-го элементов и возможного "хвоста" из остальных:

```
function ABBA(s) {
    var a = s.split(" ");
    if( a.length < 2) return s;
    return [ a[1], a[0]].concat( a.splice( 2, a.length)).join(" ");
}

alert( ABBA( 'DN63 1/4"GM 0/0,6bar'));
```

([пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/rATyC/))

Comment: Спасибо дружище

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с регулярками:

```
var ds = "Добрый День и Добрый Вечер";
var ns = ds.replace(/^([^\s]+)(\s+)([^\s]+)/, '$3$2$1');
alert(ns);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = 'DN63 1/4"GM 0/0,6bar';
    var arr = str.trim().split(' ');
    var temp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[1];
    arr[1] = temp;
    str = arr.join(' ').toString();
    alert (str);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D9C2y/5/

Comment: Зачем jQuery, `trim()` и `toString()`?